# What is a Java String's default initial value?

Tags: java, string

Consider a Java String Field named `x`.
What will be the initial value of `x` when an object is created for the class x;

I know that for `int` variables, the default value is assigned as `0`, as the instances are being created. But what becomes of `String`?

Comment: Have a look at the doc http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It's initialized to null if you do nothing, as are all reference types.

Comment: why it is not assigning as Empty String ""? Does Integer also become null?

Comment: @selvin: yes, `Integer` will be `null` as well. As the answer says: **all** reference types will be `null`. `int` however, which is a primitive type and thus not a reference type, will be `0`.

Answer (score 27):

That depends. Is it just a variable (in a method)? Or a class-member?

If it's just a variable you'll get an error that no value has been set when trying to read from it without first assinging it a value.

If it's a class-member it will be initialized to null by the VM.

Answer (score 14):

There are three types of variables:

- **Instance variables**: are always initialized
- **Static variables**: are always initialized
- **Local variables**: must be initialized before use

The default values for **instance** and **static variables** are the same and depends on the type:

- Object type (String, Integer, Boolean and others): initialized with **null**
- Primitive types:

  - byte, short, int, long: 0
  - float, double: 0.0
  - boolean: false
  - char: '\u0000'

**An array is an Object**. So an array instance variable that is declared but no explicitly initialized will have **null** value. If you declare an int[] array as instance variable it will have the null value.

Once the array is created all of its elements are assiged with the default type value. For example:

```
private boolean[] list; // default value is null

private Boolean[] list; // default value is null
```

once is initialized:

```
private boolean[] list = new boolean[10]; // all ten elements are assigned to false

private Boolean[] list = new Boolean[10]; // all ten elements are assigned to null (default Object/Boolean value)
```

Answer (score 11):

The answer is - it depends.

Is the variable an instance variable / class variable ?  See [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20120212170313/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#119097) for more details.

The list of default values can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120212170313/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#96595).

Comment: It doesn't depend.. all reference types are set to null.

Answer (score 5):

Any object if it is initailised , its defeault value is null, until unless we explicitly provide a default value.