# How to pass null parameters using ReSTClient API to the method for executing Web Service

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, model, rest-client

I'm using WizTools.org RESTClient 3.2.2 & want to pass input parameters as

```
{
"user_id": "",
"user_email_id": "a@a.a",
"user_password": "fdsdsdf",
"firstname": "sdfsdf",
"lastname": "sfdsdfds",
"mobile_number": "1234567890",
"user_status": 1,
"isdeleted": 0,
"created_by": 1,
"profile_picturename": "kfksdjfhksjd",
"address": "sfdsdfsd"
```

}

Here to create an new record i want to pass user id as "user_id": "", but rest client is showing exception as "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'pv_user_id' at row 44"

Can anyone suggest me how to pass null value to userID, my model class is as

```
@Column(name = "user_id")
private String user_id;
@Id
@Column(name = "user_email_id")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email_Id.")
@Email
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
private String user_email_id;
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
@Column(name = "user_password")
private String user_password;
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your firstName.")
@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your lastName.")
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
// @NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp = "(^[0-9]{10,12}$)", message = "Please enter your Mobile Number.")
@NumberFormat
// @Size(min = 10, max = 12)
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
private String mobile_number;
@Column(name = "user_status")
private Integer user_status;
@Column(name = "isdeleted")
private Integer isdeleted;
@Column(name = "created_by")
private Integer created_by;
@Column(name = "profile_picturename")
private String profile_picturename;
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: simply don't write userid. it will pass userid as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll not pass userId parameter it will take userId=null because userId is String and if you do not pass anything it will automatically take it as null.

Even this link will be helpful to understand the reasons..

[What is a Java String's default initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389200/what-is-a-java-strings-default-initial-value)