# How to avoid else condition with ?(ternary operator) in one line

Tags: java

Suppose that i have given below syntax:

```
Boolean isCapital = city.isCapital();
    String isCapitalName;
    if(isCapital == null) {
      isCapitalName = "";
    }
```

Means that i do not want else condition in my short for(The header of this blog) then what should be the syntax.

I want to minimize the use of if else condition in my project so that i want to use on liner if else.

Please guide.

Comment: Why are you assigning `isCapitalName` an empty string? What should `isCapitalName` be assigned to if `isCapital` is not null?

Comment: There is no ternary operator without an `else` clause. But you can omit the `{}` e.g. `if(someCondition) isCapitalName=="";` in a single line

Comment: @L.Spillner while true, most style guides (including [Google's Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)) disallow the neglection of parentheses with good reason: later modifications are more bug-prone since you "assume" the parentheses are there.

Comment: I would expect a method called "isCapital()" to return either `true` or `false` not `true`, `false` or `null`. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for the clarification. I knew that but Just wanted to open up the possibility ;).

Answer (score 6):

You can set `isCapitalName` like so:

```
String isCapitalName = isCapital == null ? "" : null;
```

This has an identical behavior to your current code. It sets it to:

- an empty string `""` if `isCapital == null`
- `null` by default

---

Edit taking into account @khelwood's comment:

The default value of an uninitialized local variable is not actually `null`, but it would cause an error if you used it in your code. I'm not sure why you would leave it uninitialized, however -- you probably want to choose a default value to put in the second clause of the ternary.

Comment: Shorter `String isCapitalName = city.isCapital() ? "" : null;` no need for `isCapital `

Comment: It doesn't have identical behaviour to the OP's code. In the OP's code, `isCapitalName` is unusable because on some branches it is _unassigned_ (not null).

Comment: @khelwood Isn't string set to `null` when uninitialized? Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389200/what-is-a-java-strings-default-initial-value)

Comment: @JonathanLam That's talking about a field, not a local variable. If a local variable is unassigned, the compiler regards it as having no value at all, not even null.

Comment: @YCF_L I would be a little cautious to do that in case the `isCapital` variable is used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @khelwood I was unaware of that. I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: @JonathanLam the compiler will even throw an error if it can find an execution path to the use a local variable so that is has not yet been initialized before.

Comment: @Turing85 and @khelwood That's very interesting information! I've been so used to using JavaScript and its weak error checking and having everything set to `undefined` by default that I totally missed this feature of Java.

Comment: @JonathanLam [JLS, §16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html): "*[...] For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs. [...]*"