# What am i doing wrong. copy the the values of s1 into the element von s2

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to copy the values of the variable s1 into the element of s2 and I am  getting null. What am I doing wrong. Here are my Code:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String[] s1 = new String[10];
       String[] s2 = new String[10];
       String[] s3 = new String[10];

       
       for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
           s2[i] = s1[i];
           System.out.println("s2[" + i + "] : " + s2[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

-------- output -------

```
s2[0] : null
s2[1] : null
s2[2] : null
s2[3] : null
s2[4] : null
s2[5] : null
s2[6] : null
s2[7] : null
s2[8] : null
s2[9] : null
```

Comment: By default, a new object array only contains `null` values . You currently never assign any `String` to any of those arrays.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to allocation some contend for each of the array positions.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (If your posted code is incomplete and the part that is initializing elements of `s1` is omitted). Also please describe your expected behavior (output).

Comment: Related: [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed the following: String [] s1 = {"3", "4", "5"}; Everything is now correct and resolved. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out to initialise s1 array. By default, it will contains null values which you are copying into s2, hence null values.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] s1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        String[] s2 = new String[10];
        String[] s3 = new String[10];

   
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++){
            s2[i] = s1[i];
            System.out.println("s2[" + i + "] : " + s2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.
Right. The declaration of S1 was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You have created an empty array of Strings, but you have not assigned any content to the individual strings. A string defaults to `null`, so your output is completely normal.

You can also read this interesting post: [What is a Java String's default initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389200/what-is-a-java-strings-default-initial-value)

If you want to see any result different from *null*, you have to initialize the first array, by using:

```
String[] s1 = {"First string", "Second string", ... }
```

or (before the *for* loop, obviously)

```
s1[1] = "First string"
s1[2] = "Second string"
...
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed the following: 
String [] s1 = {"3", "4", "5"};

Everything is now correct and resolved. thank you

Comment: @Kali Glad to have been helpful! If my answer has solved your problem, you can select it as "accepted" by clicking on the "v" button to the left of my answer :D

Comment: Sory Calaf, but: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: There is another button. It is a "check" button located under the arrows you pressed. Those are used to evaluate an answer (and give +1 or -1 to it), while the other button is to say that the answer has solved the problem. When you press on that button, you gain +2 reputation :D

Comment: You can also read this to understand how stackoverflow works: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)